# Save a file after a perl script runs on a web page

Tags: html, perl, download, prompt

I have a web page that will be used to create KML Files with a perl script.I want the user to add some data to a form that will be used in my perl script. When the form is submitted it will run the script, create a kml file, then prompt the user to save the file. The only part I am not sure about is how to have the user save the file after the script has created the KML. Do I have the perl script prompt the download or use something on the HTML page prompt the download. I am not sure the best way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a link or a form for telling the server to build the KML then just generate the KML normally and send it back to the browser with some extra HTTP headers. The headers you want are:

- `Content-disposition` set to `attachment;filename=whatever.kml` where "whatever.kml" is what you want the file to be called.
- `Content-type` set to `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml`.

The `Content-disposition` should tell the browser to download the KML instead of trying to handle it.

So the Perl script will be prompting the browser to prompt the download.

Comment: (And the relevance of google-earth?) OK, I see: that's what KML is.

Comment: When you say send it back with some extra HTTP headers, how do you mean? Do you mean the top few lines of the actual file or send the Headers to the actual page. I am not even really sure how to send the file to the page. I was just able to create the file and store it on the hosting, but that doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: @shinjuo: The perl script is running on a server and is being executed from a remote HTML page, right? So, you'd send the KML back in the same way that you'd send HTML back: print it (probably). The details of how you send data back to the browser and how you set HTTP headers will depend on how the script is hosted and what framework is used: old school CGI, FastCGI, mod_perl, Catalyst, Dancer, ...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the contents of the kml file are in $kml then you'd want to do something like:

```
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

print $cgi->header('-Content-disposition' => 'attachment;filename=kml.xml',
                   '-Content-type'        => 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');

print $kml;
```